# Student attendance time in time out

Tags: vb.net

i made a student attendance system using barcode scanner and its already working the time in time out works well but my problem is this after the student scan his/her barcode for time out the next time he/she scan his/her barcode the remarks should be time in but my code only sticks with a time out remarks.

this is my code for time in time out

```
 Dim check As Boolean


    Call connect()
    Dim cmdd As New MySqlCommand("Select Count(*) from attendance_for_student WHERE Remarks = 'IN' ", dbconn)
    Dim i As Integer = cmdd.ExecuteScalar()
    cmdd = Nothing
    dbconn.Close()
    TextBox1 .Text = i

    If student.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Scan Your Code!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

    Else

        Call connect()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE Sbarcode='" & student.Text & "'"
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader


        Do While dbread.Read
            Dim id As String = student.Text
            Dim folder As String = "c:\jpnhs\"
            Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, id & ".bmp")
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filename)
            FULLNAME.Text = dbread.Item(1).ToString & " " & dbread.Item(2).ToString & " " & dbread.Item(3).ToString
        Loop
        dbread.Close()
        dbconn.Close()
    End If
    If Len(student.Text) = 8 Then
        Call connect()
        check = False

        sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance_for_student WHERE Sbarcode = '" & student.Text & "' AND (remarks <>'IN' OR remarks <>'OUT')"
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader

        Do While dbread.Read

            check = True
        Loop
        dbread.Close()
        dbconn.Close()



        If check = False Then
            Call connect()
            sql = "INSERT INTO attendance_for_student(Sbarcode,Time,Date,remarks) VALUES ('" & student.Text & "','" & LBLTime.Text & "','" & LBLDate.Text & "','IN')"
            dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
            dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
            dbread.Close()

            dbconn.Close()
            Search_Code()

        Else
            Call connect()
            sql = "INSERT INTO attendance_for_student(Sbarcode,Time,Date,remarks) VALUES ('" & student.Text & "','" & LBLTime.Text & "','" & LBLDate.Text & "','OUT')"
            dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
            dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
            dbread.Close()

            dbconn.Close()
            Search_Code()

        End If 
    End If
```

Comment: If you want to determine if the last activity was a IN or OUT, you should ORDER BY Date and Time DESC and only select the TOP 1. Try to debug and you will very likely find out that `check` will never be `False`.

Comment: Use parameters aswell.

Comment: @Filburt thanks sir!